# Copying top-level data files to site-packages

Tags: python, pip, packaging

I have the following folder structure:

```
mypkg/
   -- setup.py
  |
   -- src/
       |
        -- mypkg/
             |
              -- actual source files (.py)
  |
   -- supporting_files/
  |
   -- ...
```

What I'm trying to achieve is, after installing `mypkg` with *pip*, to get `supporting_files` to end up next to the source files in `site-packages`.

I found how to include `supporting_files` in the distributed package, using `recursive-include supporting_files` in the `MANIFEST.in` and `include_package_data=True` in `setup.py`.
So, when I run `python setup.py sdist`, I end up with an archive which contains `supporting_files`.

However, when I do `pip install mypkg-1.0.0.tar.gz`, I end up only with the source files in my virtual environment's `site-packages/mypkg` folder. I checked if the supporting files are present in another folder within my virtual environment, but they aren't.

I found [this information](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non-code-files.html), which is what I did already but doesn't work:

> In order for these files [non-code files] to be copied at install time to the package’s folder inside site-packages, you’ll need to supply `include_package_data=True` to the `setup()` function.